# Is there a simpler way to copy a file from a computer to a Raspberry Pi over Ethernet than having to manually set an IP for both computers?

Tags: linux-mint, raspberry-pi, raspbian, ethernet, network-interface

Forgive me if I do not provide all the necessary details, but I will try my best.

I downloaded this pdf to help me get started with using my Raspberry Pi. I wanted to copy it over to my Pi, which is running Raspbian, so I connected my PC, running Linux Mint Rafaela 17.2 Cinnamon, to my Raspberry Pi, using an Ethernet Cable. I thought the process would be relatively simple: both computers would detect the other one, and would give me the option to mount the other one's file system. However, it wasn't so simple. After a fair amount of research, I succeeded in my goal by:

1. Manually setting up the eth0 interface on both the PC and Pi.
2. Mounting the Pi onto my PC using sshfs.
3. Attempting to use the GUI to drag the file onto my Pi's file system, but, after for some reason the file manager completely stopped working, and I couldn't even use commands like ls in the terminal on my PC, so I had to reboot.
4. Remounting the Pi after rebooting and instead using the terminal to copy it over.
5. Success at last!

I am fairly certain there is a much simpler way. Could anyone help me figure that out?

Comment: What command did you use when you say that you ended up "using the terminal to copy [the file] over"?

Comment: It is that complicated; however, you can automount the remote system by editing your fstab.  I recommend you read up on automounting and the fstab, as well as on sshfs vs NFS.  BTW, GUI = weakness, CLI = power.

Comment: So is there any other simpler automatic user-friendly way to first establish a connection between the two that allows for pinging and mounting file systems?

Comment: Define "user-friendly".  You can set up a way to automount remote file systems.  It requires editing the fstab among other things, which many people would not consider a n00b thing to do; but if you're mounting remote file systems from the command line, you can manage it.  I don't use Linux Mint (I mainly use Arch, which has a number of diferences in this area) but I'd suggest this article: https://ksearch.wordpress.com/2010/09/29/nfs-linux-mint/; also read up on automounting.  You probably want to automount on demand rather than at boot.

Comment: Is there a way to just establish the TCP/IP connection automatically without having to manually set the eth0 interface for either computer?

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of Raspbian (which use `dhcpcd`) allow `ssh` to work over a link-local address and `avahai` (which is a zeroconf implementation) enables programs to discover hosts running on a local network.

This means you can plug the Pi into a Computer (with an Ethernet cable) or a local network router and connect without knowing the IP address.

You can easily connect from Linux and OS X with ssh pi@hostname.local (the default hostname is raspberrypi). Other networking tools `scp` and `VNC` can also be used.

Comment: So if my hostname was raspberrypi, I could just enter ssh pi@raspberrypi.local, and it would work?

Comment: @Rohan provided you are using post May Raspbian with default `dhcpcd` (and haven't broken it by attempting manual configuration). The host also needs `zeroconf`, but most Linux have this as standard.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simpler way to copy a file from a computer to a Raspberry
>   Pi over Ethernet than having to manually set an IP for both computers?

If you are transferring data over an ethernet cable, you will always need IP addresses assigned to each device's interface.

Other ways of transferring files is to set up your computer as a DHCP server, so when you directly connect the pi you can get an IP through DHCP automatically, or what it easiest for me, is to wire the pi into the router (ideally get a USB wifi card), get a DHCP lease from router, edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file on the pi, and use `scp` to copy the files from the host to the pi.

Answer (score 0):

> I am fairly certain there is a much simpler way. Could anyone help me figure that out?

Are you able to have both devices connected to your network, and then configure an ssh server on the pi? This way you can merely scp a file over to or from the pi no problem. Personally this is what I would do.

[Take a look at this tutorial](https://roughlea.wordpress.com/raspberry-pi-experiences/configuring-the-raspberry-pi-as-an-ssh-server/), it should be everything you need to get going.

Answer (score 0):

Most recent versions of Raspbian have ssh and avahi daemon installed and set to start on boot. So long as you are on the same network you can use `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` to login to pi. Same way, you can use `scp` to transfer files, using the command line. Example, on your computer,

`scp /path/to/local/file pi@raspberrypi.local:/absolute/path/to/destination`.

This copies a local file to the pi.

If there is no absolute path specified, it copies to the home folder. This works in reverse too. You can copy the files on pi to your computer, by reversing the source and destination.

This way you don't have to look for its IP address.

(The username and hostname are defaults for pi and may need to be changed).

Comment: 90% of your answer is pretty much identical with what Milliways already wrote.